# How run multiple queries in a row

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have a table for storing storing page visit counts. The first statement firs makes a query to get the current stored data, and the second increments the first result and updates the table.

here is an example.

```
$conn = new PDO(...); 
//get current value
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT counter FROM table");
$newValue = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

//increment
$stmt = $conn->prepare("update table set counter = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($newValue));
```

The above is just an example, But I need an approach where it involves making a single `prepare()` to count and update the counter by 1, on each page visit.

Comment: If that's an example, it needs to be clarified.  Does `table` have only one row? Your `UPDATE` statement has no `WHERE` clause and would therefore affect all rows if there are multiple. And if there are multiple rows, perhaps you ought to use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will take the column value and increment itself by one (or whatever you'd like) in a single statement

```
UPDATE table SET counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: I didn't know we could use expressions inside mysql statements

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this query:

```
update table set counter = (counter+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
UPDATE table SET counter = ((SELECT counter FROM table)+1)
```

I hope this help u :)